# Why is recycler view not showing any posts with error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using multiple queries to fill a ReceyclerView however I keep getting the error `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` the issue is not that I am not calling the `RecyclerView` in `OnCreate` since all of that code is in `OnCreate`

I have already checked that my `RecyclerView` is my `OnCreate` so it is not that.

**Update:**`OnCreate`:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        final List<String> followingList = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
        final FollowerAdapter followerAdapter = new FollowerAdapter(postList);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(followerAdapter);

        Query first = userFollowingReference;//TODO Realtime updates
        first.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String id = document.getId();
                        followingList.add(id);
                    }
                    followerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if(!followingList.isEmpty()) {

                        Query second = rootRef.collection("posts/" + followingList.get(0) + "/userPosts")
                                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                                .limit(3);
                        second.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                        Post post = document.toObject(Post.class);
                                        postList.add(post);
                                    }
                                    followerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    if(!postList.isEmpty()) {
                                        lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

                                        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                                                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                                                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                                                    isScrolling = true;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                                                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                                                lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                                                int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                                                int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                                                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                                                if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                                                    isScrolling = false;

                                                    Query third = rootRef.collection("posts/" + followingList.get(task.getResult().size() - 1) + "/userPosts")
                                                            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                                                            .startAfter(lastVisible).limit(3);
                                                    third.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                                                            if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                for (DocumentSnapshot d : t.getResult()) {
                                                                    Post post = d.toObject(Post.class);
                                                                    postList.add(post);
                                                                }
                                                                followerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                                lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

                                                                if (t.getResult().size() < 3) {
                                                                    isLastItemReached = true;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        };

                                        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;

    }
```

Adapter:

```
class FollowerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> list;

    FollowerAdapter(List<Post> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post post = list.get(position);
        holder.setPost(post);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


}
```

When I run the app the `RecyclerView` is empty and I get the error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Also through debugging I found that the `followingList` is being properly filled as is the `list` that holds the posts. It looks as if The `RecyclerView` is being skipped completely.

**Edit:** Here is my Firestore layout if that is helpful

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- name: "User Name"
   |          |
   |          --- email: "email@email.com"
   |
   --- following (collection)
   |      |
   |      --- uid (document)
   |           |
   |           --- userFollowing (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |
   --- posts (collection)
         |
         --- uid (documents)
              |
              --- userPosts (collection)
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
```

Thank you so far for everyone's help!

**Update:**
I am now able to see several posts but after scrolling to the bottom of the `RecyclerView` I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`
Bellow is my Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android, 
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.android.Fragments.FollowingFragment$1$1$1.onScrolled(FollowingFragment.java:104)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5077)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5241)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Could you show your oncreate method code

Comment: @AshokKumar I have added the ```OnCreate```

Comment: @Bjorn did any of the answers were useful??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's not finding any data on your RecyclerView on its initial layout pass. You should move your adapter set up outside of your `OnCompleteListener` then update the data from within it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Your set up/initialization

    recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

    first.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task){
            // Update your adapter and notifyDataSetChanged when needed here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the changes you suggested, the error message is gone now, but I still cannot see the ```RecyclerView``` .

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data-parts are fine,

`RecyclerView` needs these to display the content.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager) // ?
recyclerView.setAdapter(...)
```

Make sure you call these method properly, and you can update if there's still problems.

---

Update:

I think your onComplete is not on the mainThread.

make sure you call `recyclerView.setAdapter(followerAdapter);` from `MainThread`.

in fact you can put `setLayoutManager` and `setAdapter` in `onCreateView()` stage, just call `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `onComplete()`.

Comment: Have I added them properly? I have updated the question.

Comment: I thought I did call ```notifyDataSetChanged``` in ```OnComplete```? In both cases it is right below the ```foreach```.

Comment: Try Log `Thread.currentThread.name` to see if it's mainThread

Comment: I ran ```System.out.println(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper());``` and it returned true so it is in the main thread. I will update what I have since I have made changes that changed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

followerAdapter is passed with postlist , it should be followinglist.

Also in query2 postlist is currently not updating with fetched data